# Create action in polymorphic association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, null

I'm having trouble with the `create` action in my `plannings_controller`.

```
def new
  @plannable = find_plannable
  @planning = @plannable.plannings.build
  3.times { @planning.periods.build }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @planning }
  end
end


def create
  @plannable = find_plannable
  @planning = @plannable.plannings.build(params[:planning])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @planning.save
      format.html { redirect_to @plannable }
      format.json { render json: @planning, status: :created, location: @plannable }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @planning.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def find_plannable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

In the `#new` action, the `find_plannable` method returns the value I want, but in the `#create` action it returns nil and I have no idea why this is happening.

My models are just like Ryan Bates' in the rails cast polymorphic episode:

```
#PLANNING MODEL
class Planning < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subsubsystem_id, :subsystem_id, :system_id, :plannable_type, :plannable_id, :periods_attributes, :_destroy
  has_many :periods, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :plannable, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :periods, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:planned_quantity].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

#SUBSUBSYSTEM MODEL
class Subsubsystem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hh, :name, :percentage, :price, :subsystem_id, :total_quantity, :unity, :value, :weight
  belongs_to :subsystem
  has_many :plannings, :as => :plannable
end
```

Can anyone help me?! thanks in advance!

edit: parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"vSr7C1+3+RhYArAmYz+zuAsLXsXriwouF771bn79+Is=",
 "planning"=>{"periods_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"planned_quantity"=>"11"},
 "1"=>{"planned_quantity"=>"6"},
 "2"=>{"planned_quantity"=>"8"}},
 "_destroy"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"OK"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the POST parameters, there isn't such a field matching `/(.+)_id$/`, so, your attempt to find the class will fail inside `find_plannable`

The simple fix is, in #new, add a hidden field of the plannable_id inside the form. You've already got `@plannable` there, so that's easy.

Then you'll have `plannable_id` and its value to feed `find_plannable`.

Comment: Thanks man, but can you be more specific? I didn't undestand how Im supposed to code that...

Comment: To use the param, you must have that param. The params come from either path or form field. The #new page is a form, you can add a new field(say hidden field) there with default value as planner_id, so this param will be sent together with form submission and you can use it in #create.

Comment: you mean like `<%= f.hidden_field :plannable_id, :value => @plannable.id %>`?

Comment: but how can i feed `find_plannable` with that parameter?

Comment: Yes, I meant that code. To find it in #create: `Plan.find(params[:plannable_id])`

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what table do I have to use `.find`? Already tried it by adding another hidden_field with value set to `@plannable.class.to_s` and then in #create using if clauses to compare with strings such as "Subsubsystem". For example `if :plannable_type == "Subsubsystem"
      @plannable = Subsubsystem.find(params[:plannable_id])`. It's still returning nil...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your params it seems that you are having different value for params in case of create and new. Can you please post params hash for both create and new, it may help others is solving your problem

Comment: edited question, posted the parameters in the POST of `PlanningsController#create`

Comment: where can I find the #new action parameters?

Comment: You may find them in server or you may log them for you again in log file using Rails.logger.debug "#{params}"

Or you may print them in view file using <%= y params %>